# Cell Match partial Table element Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a client name and I want to know if the client is already known having a shorter name of the company.

The client list is more detailled than the client short name.
Exemple : "COMPANY INC US" is known as "COMPANY".

I'm searching for something like this but it doesn't work.

```
=EQUIV([@Client];Table[Client_short_name]&"*";0)
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You could try index/match, with match looking for approximates (set third parameter to 1).

Or you could use something like this 
`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(short_name, full_name))`

Comment: I can't use approximate, I could have a new client. The formula does'nt work, that's the same, it can be a new client

Comment: @Clemsang is it always the same naming convention: "short_name *" ? If so, you could use `split()` and have the denominator as " ". (space)

Comment: With a new client, if you don't find it with an approximate match, it means that you don't have that client yet, doesn't it?

Comment: I can have "Man1 Man2 TRANSPORT LIMITED" with "Man1 Man2". The approximate might give something false, like string begining with "AGENCY"

Comment: Could there also be "Man1 Man2 Man3" in the list? Then using approximate match would be dangerous... Otherwise it would work for your problem, I think.

Comment: Yes. The short name is include in the long name. Some short names have the same begining.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115099/discussion-between-clemsang-and-sun).